# How can I directly enter the chrome dragon jump game?

Tags: google-chrome

When my network down, I can play this in chrome.

[image]

How can I directly enter this page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this link for playing jumping dino: chrome://dino

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same game in the following URL

http://www.trex-game.skipser.com/

Give a try!

Comment: This is not internal link, I expected something like `chrome://`,but thanks,it works.